# How to run X/Cygwin without first running cygwin.bat?

Tags: windows, cygwin, cygwin-x

To run any GUI program, I need first run a `startxwin`, which has no EXE extension. So I need first run `cygwin.bat`. `startxwin` only starts GUI terminal by default, so I am obliged to run 2 intermediate terminals to run any GUI cygwin application.

Is it possible to simplify this process?

May be run XWindow without runnin DOS bat file?

Comment: @Ramhound you cannot associate Auto launching software if files have no extension. I believe the exe you're looking for is XWin.exe, but I'm not a hundred percent

Comment: @Ramhound Because its still relevant?

Comment: No, A three year old comment is definitely not relevant.  Especially if you reply to it with an incomplete statement.  Doesn’t matter I did what I should have done 3 years ago and deleted my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startxwin is a shell script (/usr/bin/startxwin).  It creates the magic cookie file (to prevent from unauthorized programs from taking over your screen), and then does a normal "xinit".  Here's the command it uses to start a server on my box:

eval xinit "/etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc"  -- "/usr/bin/XWin" :0 -multiwindow  -nolisten tcp -auth '/home/MY_USERNAME/.serverauth.1648'

The startxwinrc tries to spawn "something" that has the cookie and display stuff set for you.

It also takes many parameters: type 'man startxwin' for help.

But, for your shortest and simplest answer, create a shortcut with the following command, and it will start your X server, without any output or extra windows:

`C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe -p /usr/X11R6/bin XWin -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error`

That should set you up.  (If you installed cygwin somewhere other than c:\cygwin, just fix the first part of that shortcut)